# Powershell: Move Items Based on Destination from Hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm attempting to write a PowerShell script to move files from one directory to another based on a few conditions. For example:

1. An example of a file name: testingcenter123456-testtype-222-412014.pdf.
2. The script should look for "testingcenter123456" before the first dash ("-") and then refer to a hash table for a matching key. All the files follow the format shown above.
3. Once its finds that key, it should use that key's corresponding value (example: "c:\temp\destination\customer7890") as the destination file path and copy the file there.

I looked around StackOverflow and found a few Q&As that seemed to answer parts of similar questions but the fact that I'm very new to this has led to the script I pieced together not working at all.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$hashTable = ConvertFrom-StringData ([IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\temp\filepaths.txt"))
$directory = "c:\temp\source"
Get-ChildItem $directory |
    where {!($_.PsIsContainer)} |
    Foreach-Object {
    Foreach ($key in $hashTable.GetEnumerator()){
       if ($_.Name.Substring(0,$_.Name.IndexOf("-")) -eq $key.Name){
       Copy-Item -Path $_.fullname -Destination $key.Value
       }
    }
    }
```

If anyone can help me get un-stuck and hopefully learn a little something about PowerShell in the process, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Could you maybe tell us what's going on when you run this? :) Do you get an error or an unintended result? That will help us pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Did you print out $key and $key.value to check the content (meaning does the filepath.txt has a good format ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not seeing why this shouldn't work.  It would be helpful if you told us which line was generating an error.

```
Foreach ($key in $hashTable.GetEnumerator()) {
   if ($_.Name.Substring(0,$_.Name.IndexOf("-")) -eq $key.Name) {
   Copy-Item -Path $_.fullname -Destination $key.Value
   }
}
```

That said, you're missing the point of using hashtable by looping through its entries, manually matching on key.  With a hashtable, you don't need to loop e.g.

```
$hashTable = ConvertFrom-StringData ([IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\temp\filepaths.txt"))
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\source |
Where {!($_.PsIsContainer)} |
Foreach-Object {
    $key =  $_.Name.Substring(0,$_.Name.IndexOf("-"))
    $val = $hashtable.$key
    if ($val) {
        $_ | Copy-Item -Dest $val -WhatIf
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No entry for $key"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Keith Hill I was getting several errors that were all related to various issues in the hash file itself. I fixed each of those errors and then ran my original script. No errors but also no results. Nothing happened.

Thanks for the tip regarding the manual looping through hashtable entries. I actually re-wrote my original script using your suggestion and was returned 'WARNING: No entry for VSMDABC001' for each key. I'm not sure what I'm missing here but it seems the issue with the previous script is related to this issue.

Comment: This warning is telling you that the key "VSMABC001" doesn't existi in your $hashtable. You might check the file to make sure there is an entry for that key.  Check the contents of `$hastTable` after using `ConvertFrom-StringData`.  I found I had to double-up backslashes to get my test string to read correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I also had to add the double backslashes. I'll take a closer look at the hashtable. The error is returning for every entry so I'm guessing I've done something wrong with the hashtable. I'll investigate a bit more and let you know if you have any questions. Thanks again for your replies!

Comment: Got it figured out -- problem with the hashtable. Thanks again for the help.